# How can I run my Javascript code for 3 seconds and then execute my c# code?

Tags: javascript, c#, css

```
protected void ans1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlCommand scmdans = new SqlCommand("SQLCOMMAND...);
        connection.Open();
        SqlDataReader readerJ = scmdans.ExecuteReader();
        while (readerJ.Read())
        {
            if (ans1.Text == (String.Format("{0}", readerJ[0])))
            {
                ytemp = "500";
                xtemp = "95";
                Session["thepos"] = ytemp;
                Session["opos"] = xtemp;

                ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), "hwa", "timer();", true);
                image.CssClass = "setcssclass";
            }
        }

    }
```

I want to run the C# code `ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript`, which is an animation of an image moving. However the next line of code sets and saves the image's position. I do this so that when I run my SQL statement the image can stay in the updated position When I remove the `image.CssClass` line I am able to see the image moving. When I keep the line the image jumps to the position the `CssClass` is set to. How can I fix this?

Comment: ...Is this Web Forms? What does this have to do with CSS?

Comment: Yes it is Web Forms. I am trying to create a digital board game using asp.net which connects to sql database and use javascript which moves the character.